# Responsive Bootstrap 4 grid for Angular 2 ngFor

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I wonder if there's a way to render responsively elements created by *ngFor in Angular 2?

I use Bootstrap 4 grid system based on flex property. And I've got this code in my Angular2 app:

```
<div class="outlet container">
<div class="row itemsBlock">
   <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="itemRender">
        <img class="itemImage" src="{{item.image}}" />
        <span class=itemitle">{{item.title}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to get my *items* rendered responsively, say

3 divs in the row on large and middle-sized displays

2 divs in the row on small ones

1 div in the row on x-small displays

Comment: Just specify all the applicable grid sizes in the class. (ie; `class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12"`). All the items can be in a single `.row` element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't really relate that stuff with looping over `items` collection. You could take use `xl`, `lg`,`md` & `sm` class with `col-size-number`(like `col-xs-12`) class on same row. Bootstrap will take care about to applying a class over element based on screen resolution.

**Markup**

```
<div class="row itemsBlock">
   <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <img class="itemImage" src="{{item.image}}" />
        <span class=itemitle">{{item.title}}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

> **Note**: The Bootstrap v4 grid system has five tiers of classes: `xs`
>   (extra small), `sm` (small), `md` (medium), `lg` (large), and `xl` (extra
>   large). You can use nearly any combination of these classes to create
>   more dynamic and flexible layouts.